# Application Crashes in formatted Android Phones

Tags: android

I am facing awkward problem.

Android Mobile Users who has formatted their handsets are not able to run my application.

In rest of Android Mobiles the application is running just fine.

Can anyone enlighten me what could be the possible reason and how can i over come such a problem.

Thanks & Regards

Krishna V. Mahadik

Answer (score 0):

Your application is referring to some data that is stored on data partition or SD card.

So after factory reset or SDCard formation, the data is gone but you did not handle such exception.

Comment: No, I have not stored any data at mobile end. I am processing everything on server and displaying output.

There are couple of things that I save by that is run-time data, which is fetched from server ever time on login.

Comment: Do you have the crash log?

Comment: I don't have crash log. Since I don't have access to formatted Android phone. I will have to arrange a formatted android phone or will have to format a android phone in order to get crash log. The application is working fine on android phone which are not formatted.